# Overwrite django view with custom context (Django 1.11, Viewflow)

Tags: python, django, django-1.11, django-viewflow

I have a Django 1.11 project using Viewflow - https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow - that I've incorporated. It's been very helpful, but a lot of stuff is kind of "magic", and being my first serious Django project, I'm running into an issue I'm not sure of how to solve, or the best way.

I have a generic template that expects a lot of context. I have a function that adds this context to all of my views:

```
def add_general_context(context, MOC, MOC_enabled_fields = (), MOC_status = None):
  context['MOC'] = MOC
  context['current_date'] = timezone.now().strftime("%D")
  context['MOC_form'] = forms.MOCForm(prefix="MOC_form", MOC_enabled_fields=MOC_enabled_fields, instance=MOC)
  context['MOCAttachments'] = models.MOCAttachment.objects.filter(MOC=MOC)
  context['MOCAttachment_form'] = forms.MOCAttachmentForm(prefix="MOCAttachment_form")
  context['MOCApprovals'] = models.MOCApproval.objects.filter(MOC=MOC)
  context['MOCTasks'] = models.MOCTask.objects.filter(MOC=MOC)
  context['MOC_status'] = MOC_status
  context['MOCConversation'] = models.MOCConversation.objects.filter(MOC=MOC)
  # Add comments to the conversation
  for conversation in context['MOCConversation']:
    conversation.comments = models.MOCComment.objects.filter(conversation=conversation)
  context['MOCComment_form'] = forms.MOCCommentForm(MOC=MOC)
  context['MOCCommentReply_form'] = forms.MOCCommentReplyForm()
```

I basically need to add this context to a view that is inside viewflow - namely, AssignTaskView - https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/f50accb3cde5d53f1d4db0debf5936867712c3bd/viewflow/flow/views/task.py#L109

I've tried a few things to overwrite/add to the context, but none seem to work.

Attempt 1: Overwrite the URL and use extra_context (SO suggested this)
 - The issue is that the urls are "magic", my urlpatterns is very simply:

```
from material.frontend import urls as frontend_urls
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^MOC/', include('MOC.urls')),
  url(r'', include(frontend_urls)),
]
```

Overwriting the urls themselves was WAY over my head, I dug into it for a while, but it uses really generic functions to pull in modules, etc. I didn't have a clue how to really even attempt it.

Attempt 2: Overwrite the view itself and the get_context_data function
I think this would be possible, but it just doesn't seem to work. My attempts looked similar to this (the lastest one):

```
from viewflow.flow.views.task import AssignTaskView as CoreAssignTaskView

class AssignTaskView(CoreAssignTaskView):
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AssignTaskView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print("Did it work?")
    return context
```

This is in my views.py - however, it simply doesn't run. I'm probably missing something, but I can't figure out how to actually force it to use *my* view instead of the one built in to viewflow.

I've successfully overwritten Viewflow's templates without issue, but overwriting anything else is beyond me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can actually override a view url by putting it on top of url_patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^/workflow/appname/flowname/(?P<process_pk>\d+)/taskname/(?P<task_pk>\d+)/assign/$',
        YouCustomView.as_view(),
        {'flow_task': FlowClass.taskname},
        name="{}__assign".format(self.name)))
    ),
    url(r'', include(frontend_urls)),
]
```

But it's simpler just to create a custom flow.View subclass and set you own Assign View

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/flow/nodes.py#L306

```
from viewflow import flow

class MyView(flow.View):
      assign_view_class = MyAssignTaskView
```

flows.py:

```
 class MyFlow(Flow):
    ...
    taskname = MyView(UpdateProcessView).next(this.end)
```

That's how you can override any of the built-in views.

Viewflow designed to provide all knobs within your codebase. You can customize any behavior by subclassing Flow or flow Node classes.

The custom node example could be helpful

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/customnode/nodes.py