# Overriding django viewflow views to return JSON

Tags: django, ajax, django-viewflow

Probably something basic, but cannot seem to figure it out.

I am trying to implement a custom UI for viewflow where the various tasks are displayed as modals. I have managed to get the initial start view to display in a modal and to use AJAX to submit the form. I would like to get all the other process task views to do the same. The following is my attempt based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073203/2645376) however, the overridden view `AJAXDetailTaskView(DetailTaskView)` does not seem to get called and I am wondering where I am going wrong.

In this specific instance I am trying to modify the start detail view (which I presume will be the same principle for all the other views)

**flows.py**

```
class AssetFlow(Flow):

    process_class = models.AssetProccess
    task_class = models.AssetTask
    lock_impl = select_for_update_lock

    start = (
        flow.Start(
            views.StartView)
        .Permission(auto_create=True)
        .Next(this.co_approval)
    )

    co_approval = (
        flow.View(
            views.AssetView
        )
        .Next(this.finance_tc)
    )

...
```

**views.py**

```
from viewflow.flow.views.detail import DetailTaskView

class AJAXDetailTaskView(DetailTaskView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

        if self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            print('An AJAX request')
            return JsonResponse('Success', safe=False, **response_kwargs)
        else:
            print('Not an AJAZ request')
            return super(AJAXDetailTaskView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)

class StartView(StartFlowMixin, generic.UpdateView, flow.View):
    model = models.Item
    form_class = forms.AssetForm
    data = dict()
    detail_view_class = AJAXDetailTaskView

    def get_object(self):
        return self.activation.process.asset

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        context = self.get_context_data(form=form, data=self.data)
        html_form = render_to_string('asset/asset/partial_start.html',
                                     context,
                                     request=request,
                                     )
        return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})
        
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detail_view_class is an attribute of flow.Start not the StartView

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried to update my code to class StartView(StartFlowMixin, generic.UpdateView, flow.Start): however, there does not seem to work. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: Sorry - it is me again! I have also tried to override the attribute in flow.py     start = (
        flow.Start(
            views.StartView,
            detail_view_class=views.AJAXDetailTaskView.as_view()
        )
        .Permission(auto_create=True)
        .Next(this.co_approval)
    ) but that does not seem to work either

Comment: OK - figured out the error! instead of modifying the flow.py with detail_view_class it should have been detail_view. Thanks again for the help!